# ANDROID - SQLite cipher loadLibs error

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

i'm trying to use cipher sqlite plugin to encript a database.
i download the project, i imported it in eclipse. then i put assets zip and libs file in my project and i modified project properties such this:
in java Built Path>libraries i added the three .jar files from libs folder
in java Built Path>projects i added the android-database-sqlitechiper which i have downloaded

at the end i changed import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase
but when i try to run it it crash.
the error occur on loadLibs function

```
SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
```

here is the error (not exception):

```
05-10 23:13:39.303: E/asd(8492): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase
```

what i'm wrong? thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already added your libraries to the build path, then try doing a Project>>Clean, this would do the trick.